# SQL variable group within another group

Tags: mysql, sql, dataset, sas

I'm looking for a way to match a set of results from a larger list of other results, and count the number of matches. For example:

I have a set of results

```
Result 1
sub1
sub2
sub3

Result 2
sub1
sub2
sub3
```

I need to find how many times either set of the above results appears in a much larger data set of results below.

```
Result 1
sub1
sub2
sub3

Result 2
sub1
sub3
sub4

Result 2
sub1
sub2
sub3

Result 2
sub1
sub2
sub3
sub4
```

In the example above, Result 1 from the first set would match the first result in the second set, and Result 2 would match the final 2 results in the second set, because they contained all the sub results from the first set. So Result 1 would show a frequency count of 1, while Result 2 would show a frequency count of 2.

I'm rather new with SQL, but would like to find a solution to the above problem.

Sample Data from yesterday:

```
Group    Ad   Date
A        1    7/14
A        2    7/14
A        3    7/14
B        1    7/14
B        2    7/14
B        3    7/14
B        4    7/14
C        1    7/14
D        1    7/14
D        3    7/14
D        4    7/14
```

I need to find out how many times Group A Ads 1-3 ran in the past week, but say on Monday Group A ran only ads 1 and 3. I don't want this result returned.  Tuesday Group A ran ads 1, 2, 3, 4. I WOULD want to know this result, Wednesday Group A had ads 1, 2, 3 run, this again I would want to know.

```
Group    Ad   Date
A        1    7/09
A        3    7/09
A        1    7/10
A        2    7/10
A        3    7/10
A        4    7/10
A        1    7/14
A        2    7/14
A        3    7/14
```

So, given the example, I would expect to see this:

```
Group    Ad   Date
A        1    7/10
A        2    7/10
A        3    7/10
A        1    7/14
A        2    7/14
A        3    7/14
```

Comment: What are the "sub"'s? Can you post some sample data and perhaps desired results?

Comment: Can you at least post a schema for us to work with? We need to know how the data is represented. Does each group have its own unique id? Are sets within their own tables or are they represented by an id?

Comment: @ZaneBien Sample data would be proprietary, so I cannot post it.  We have sets of ads that run daily. These ads run within groups.  The "Results" in the example are the groups, and the "subs" are the ads within the groups.  Not every ad within a group will run every single day.  Sometimes ads are added to the group, sometimes ads are deleted from a group.  I need to find out how many times within a specific date range, a given set of ads ran within a particular group.

Comment: We don't need your actual data, but we just need to know how your table structure is laid out so we can understand your situation better. Data that is simply made-up is perfectly fine.

Comment: Okay, great! We're getting there... just one more thing: How do you know when and what ads ran on what dates? Is it stored in another table or is everything within one table?

Comment: it's all stored on the same table.  I'll update my example above, but we have 30 days worth of data on the table.  First I pull yesterday's data to find out what ads ran, then I compare them to the past week.

Comment: If there were a way to filter by frequency, that would be a huge plus (i.e.  display only if yesterday's ads from group A show up at least 3 times in the past week).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little messy, but here is what I was able to come up with:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT 'A' AS grp, 1 AS ad UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 3
) a 
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT date
    FROM tbl
    WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
) b
LEFT JOIN tbl c ON a.grp = c.grp
               AND a.ad = c.ad
               AND b.date = c.date
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.date
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 'A' AS grp, 1 AS ad UNION ALL
        SELECT 'A', 2 UNION ALL
        SELECT 'A', 3
    ) a 
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT date
        FROM tbl
        WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
    ) b
    LEFT JOIN tbl c ON a.grp = c.grp
                   AND a.ad = c.ad
                   AND b.date = c.date
    GROUP BY a.date
    HAVING COUNT(1) = COUNT(c.grp)
) d ON b.date = d.date
```

I'm a little too tired to write an explanation, but perhaps when I wake up tomorrow, I will continue my answer.

For now, you can view a **[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de529/11/1)**. Notice I have inserted four more values than there are in your example data to showcase how the query works when a set appears more than once per day.

^ You can see in the second executed query that you can also filter the frequency the set appears in each day via `HAVING COUNT(1) >= 2`.

Comment: `COUNT(CASE WHEN c.grp IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0` can be simplified to: `COUNT(*) = COUNT(c.grp)` Or maybe remove it completely amke that `LEFT` join an `INNER` one.

Comment: @ypercube, good point, thanks. It needs all the simplification as it can use.

Comment: This is great!  Is there a way to add a little more automation into this?  I was thinking something like  Select * from table where date = yesterday GROUP BY date, group, ad... then have the result of that query feed the lookup for the rest of the week.  The datasets I'm looking at will have several tens of thousands of ads running daily.  Also, there will not always be exactly 3 ads in a group, sometimes there will be one, sometimes 2, 3, 4, 5 or more.  Thank you again!

Comment: @Tom, I'm still confused on how you define what a "group" is if everything is in the same table. Like would **A(1,2,3)** be a group? Would **A(2,3,4,5,6)** be another group? Is any combination its own group? Does it depend on date? How do you make the distinction if there are two columns (group, ad) which can have repeating values?

Answer (score 0):

In SAS SQL:

```
    proc sql;
    CREATE TABLE tbl (
      grp CHAR(1),
      ad INT,
      date DATE
    );

    INSERT INTO tbl 
    values('A', 1, '09jul2012'd) 
    values('A', 3, '09jul2012'd) 
    values('A', 1, '10jul2012'd) 
    values('A', 2, '10jul2012'd)
    values('A', 3, '10jul2012'd) 
    values('A', 4, '10jul2012'd) 
    values('A', 1, '14jul2012'd) 
    values('A', 2, '14jul2012'd) 
    values('A', 3, '14jul2012'd) 
    values('A', 1, '14jul2012'd) 
    values('A', 2, '14jul2012'd) 
    values('A', 3, '14jul2012'd) 
    ;
    quit;

    proc sql noprint; /* the set and upper date I'm interested in */
    CREATE TABLE my_set (
      grp CHAR(1),
      ad INT,
      date DATE
    );

    INSERT INTO my_set (grp, ad)
    VALUES ('A', 1)
    VALUES ('A', 2)
    VALUES ('A', 3)
    ;
    update my_set set date=today()-1;
    select count(*) into :my_set_size from my_set
    ;
    quit;

    proc sql;
    create table potential_dates as
     select t.date, s.grp, s.ad, count(*) as ad_occurrence
    from my_set s
     inner join tbl t 
        on s.grp = t.grp and s.ad = t.ad and s.date >= t.date
     group by t.date, s.grp, s.ad
    ;
    quit;

    proc sql;
        create table result as
            select a.* from potential_dates a
             inner join (select date from potential_dates
                        group by date
                        having count(*) = &my_set_size ) d
            on a.date = d.date
    ;
    quit;


 date     grp        ad  ad_occurrence
 10JUL12  A           1              1
 10JUL12  A           2              1
 10JUL12  A           3              1
 14JUL12  A           1              2
 14JUL12  A           2              2
 14JUL12  A           3              2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could sort and transpose:

```
proc sort data=mydata1;
  by group date;
run;

proc transpose data=mydata1 out=mydata2;
  by group date;
  var ad;
run;

data mydata3;
  set mydata2;
  if not missing(col1,col2,col3);
run;
```

You will have one row per date. If needed, you could merge this back on to your original data:

```
data mydata4;
  merge mydata1 mydata3;
  by group date;
run;
```